# How to make li tag display the url in the status bar of inner a tag

Tags: html

The li tag has a padding attribute.

I want to click the red blank space open the link, and show the URL when hovering on the li tag.

```css
li {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  border: solid;
  padding: 0, 18, 0, 18
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <ul>
    <li class="border">
      <a href="/'>click</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

sorry, forgot to add the link

Comment: What link? There isn't a link (or a URL) anywhere in your code.

Comment: Your CSS is invalid, the `padding` *property* won't apply.

Comment: @Quentin Given the current code, it is completely unclear what OP is asking. Close.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is not clear what you mean by `<span onClick="alert(123)">click</span>`, I assume that you mean a link tag like `<a href="http://example.com">Click</a>`.

If so, you could work with `padding-right`, so you could click on the red blank space to open the link and the URL will be displayed in the status bar.

```css
li {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  border: solid;
}

a {
  padding-right: 70px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="box">
    <ul>
    <li class="border">
      <a href="http://example.com">Click</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```